# How to avoid checking every time, if variable is set in blade template? Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I know about something like this:

```
{{ old('contents', $page->contents ?? null) }}
```

But what about more complicated cases, like checkboxes and selects?

```
<select id="custom_template" name="custom_template">
    {{--default empty option, if nothing is selected yet--}}
    <option label=" " {{ ($page->custom_template == null)? "selected" : "" }}></option>

    @foreach($templates as $template)
        <option value="{{ $template->id }}" {{ ($page->custom_template == $template->id)? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $template->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I need to avoid checking `@isset($page)` and also check old input. How can I do it in that select input?

Comment: you dont need to check for default value, if nothing is set as selected, the first option is the default

Comment: @N69S that's right, I forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Type hinting to avoid the 'isset'.

Your controller

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Entities\Page  $page
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function create(\App\Entities\Page $page)
{
    return view('page', compact('page'));
}
```

With using 'Type hinting' in create function will create empty collection of Page Entities. No need to check isset condition in view, `$page->custom_template` will give you null now, instead of error.

And your view, to check the old input.

```
<select id="custom_template" name="custom_template">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    
    @foreach($templates as $template)
        <option value="{{ $template->id }}" {{ (old('custom_template', $page->custom_template) == $template->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $template->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

By using the above condition you can use same view for create and edit function.

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works! And no more endless `@isset`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you're trying to do but this approach may help; provided you're using JQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        @if($page->custom_template)
        $('option[value="{{ $page->custom_template}}"]').prop("selected", true);
        @endif
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I use this form for store and update methods. So in the first case there is no variable $page, and I get an error about undefined variable. I can solve it with `@isset($page)`, but in this case code will be too complicated with many duplicated `@isset`, so I'm looking for more easy and elegant way.

Comment: Why can't you just separate it into 2 files: create.blade.php and edit.blade.php following Laravel convention? With that, you will need to have two routes one pointing to your create method and the other to your edit method. The big advantage of using this approach is being able to bind your model with the form fields so you won't have to set the value each time.

Comment: @WaiylKarim Using seperate view for create and update is not recommended. If you have to do any changes, then you have to do change same twice. To avoid duplicate code we have to use same view. Check out my answer, for how to use same view for both functionally.